# how to use utc timestamp symfony 4?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony4, doctrine-extensions

How to use utc_timestamp in Symfony 4?

Getting below message while using `utc_timestamp`

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 199 near 'UTC_TIMESTAMP': Error:
> 'UTC_TIMESTAMP' is not defined.

Comment: Is there any code involved that you want to share? That's not an error thrown by Symfony itself

Comment: @NicoHaase
i tried this but not working
This is doctirne dql query

@$qb->andWhere("(pv.appointmentDate) >= UTC_TIMESTAMP");

Comment: Please add everything that is relevant into the question, don't use the comment section for that. And: obviously, you are using any random **string** and not a function in your code. Have a look at https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions

Comment: @NicoHaase i want to use like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55624934/getting-error-while-using-interval-in-doctrine

Comment: You're welcome to do so, but you have to do something for it. It won't work out of the box

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use utc_timestamp with doctrine. you can include library in doctrine.yaml file.

```
orm:
        dql:
            string_functions:
                UTC_TIMESTAMP: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\UtcTimestamp
```

Check with above code. Might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is wrong way to use it. UTC_TIMESTAMP use with parentheses. it should like:

```
$qb->andWhere("(pv.appointmentDate) >= UTC_TIMESTAMP()");
```